# Palabra pass y * en los parametros de funciones?

Tags: python-3.x, funciones, pycharm, parametros, modulos

Quería ver como se han realizado algunas funciones integradas en Python y esto me ha llevado a meterme a los módulos.

Yo utilizo Pycharm, y para ver el codigo de la funciones integradas en Python o hechas por mi, lo hago con **CTRL + CLICK EN LA FUNCION**, esto me redirige a la funcion. He estado mirando el modulo **builtins.py** y me he fijado que en varias funciones por ejemplo `getattr()`, no contiene codigo, solo llevan una palabra reservada que es `pass`, esto a que se debe? a caso están ocultas las funciones?

```
def getattr(object, name, default=None):
    pass
```

Por otra parte he visto que hay otras funciones como:

```
def format(*args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

Que significado tiene los asteriscos `*` y los dobles `**`, en los parámetros ?

Comment: son dos preguntas diferentes, sería mejor separarlas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `pass`

`pass` es una sentencia que no hace nada. Suele usarse en el cuerpo de una función cuando no se desea implementar la función, pero sí que exista. En Python no puedes dejar un bloque vacío, porque no tiene llaves para delimitar bloques, de modo que se usa la sentencia `pass` para representar un bloque vacío. También puedes ver a veces `...` en su lugar, que también es palabra reservada python (si bien no es una sentencia, sino una constante)

¿Por qué podrías querer tener un método sin implementación? Típicamente porque forma parte de una clase que tendrá otras clases derivadas que serán quienes implementen el método. Sería el concepto "método abstracto" en OOP.

### Asteriscos

Un asterisco delante de un parámetro en una función indica que ese único parámetro "recogerá" todos los parámetros posicionales que se le pasen a la función, y los hará disponibles en una tupla.

Es decir, si escribo esto:

```
def prueba(*parametros):
   print(parametros)
```

`parametros` será una tupla que contendrá todos los parámetros que se le pasen a la función, de modo que si la invocas así: `prueba(1,2,3,4)` la variable `parametros` recibirá la tupla `(1,2,3,4)`

Por otro lado el doble asterisco hace algo similar, pero con parámetros "con nombre". Al poner doble asterisco delante de un parámetro en una función, ese parámetro "recogerá" todos los parámetros con nombre que se le pasen en la invocación, y los hará disponibles para la función en un diccionario (las claves serían los nombres).

Ejemplo:

```
def prueba(**parametros):
    print(parametros)
```

Entonces puedes llamarla así `prueba(a=1, b=2)` y en ese caso `parametros` será el diccionario `{"a": 1, "b": 2}`.

Esto da mucha flexibilidad para declarar funciones de las que no sabes cuántos ni cuáles parámetros posicionales o con nombres va a recibir. Es típico también llamar `args` y `kwargs` a estos dos parámetros, pero no son palabras reservadas, es simplemente una convención.

El asterisco y doble asterisco también se pueden usar en la invocación de una función, y entonces hacen lo contrario. Es decir el asterisco "desempaqueta" una tupla (o lista) en una serie de parámetros posicionales, y el doble asterisco "desempaqueta" un diccionario en una serie de parámetros con nombre.

De este modo las dos formas que muestro a continuación de invocar a una función son equivalentes:

```py
posicionales = (1,2,3)
con_nombre = {"x": 2.5, "y": 33 }
llamada(*posicionales, **con_nombre)

# Equivale a
llamada(1, 2, 3, x=2.5, y=33)
```

Típicamente esto se usa en decoradores, para aceptar cualquier número de parámetros y poder pasárselos después a la función decorada.