# ¿Cuál es el significado de un * solitario como argumento de un método?

Tags: python

Estaba leyendo el código del módulo subprocess y llego a este fragmento de código (164 a 173 líneas):

```
if _mswindows:
    class STARTUPINFO:
        def __init__(self, *, dwFlags=0, hStdInput=None, hStdOutput=None,
                     hStdError=None, wShowWindow=0, lpAttributeList=None):
            self.dwFlags = dwFlags
            self.hStdInput = hStdInput
            self.hStdOutput = hStdOutput
            self.hStdError = hStdError
            self.wShowWindow = wShowWindow
            self.lpAttributeList = lpAttributeList or {"handle_list": []}
```

¿Alguien sabe qué hace el argumento *?
Al buscar en Internet solo encontré lo común (* args, ** kwargs), no sé si está relacionado con eso.

Comment: Hey men, this is SO in spanish... maybe you want [SO] or translate it..

Comment: jaja lo he puesto en la cuenta que no es

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/363743/80870

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Palabra pass y \* en los parametros de funciones?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/363741/palabra-pass-y-en-los-parametros-de-funciones)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El `*` indica que la función solo permite parámetros con palabras clave. Se agregó en el [PEP 3102](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/).

---

#### Explicación

> Por defecto, los argumentos pueden enviarse a una función Python o bien por posición o explícitamente por clave. Para legibilidad y rendimiento tiene sentido restringir como se pueden enviar los argumentos, así un desarrollador necesitará mirar solamente la definición de la función para determinar si los argumentos se deben enviar por posición, por posición o clave, o por clave.
> La definición de una función puede ser como la siguiente:

```
def f(pos1, pos2, /, pos_or_kwd, *, kwd1, kwd2):
      -----------    ----------     ----------
        |             |                  |
        |        Positional or keyword   |
        |                                - Keyword only
         -- Positional only
```

> donde / y * son posicionales. Si se utilizan, esos símbolos indican el tipo de parámetro por como los argumentos deben enviarse a la función: solo por posición (positional-only), por posición o clave (positional-or-keyword) y solo por clave (keyword-only). Parámetros por clave pueden también denominarse parámetros por nombre o nombrados. [Parámetros especiales](https://docs.python.org/es/dev/tutorial/controlflow.html#special-parameters)

#### Ejemplo

```
  def kwd_only_arg(*, arg):
       print(arg)
```

---

```
>>> kwd_only_arg(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: kwd_only_arg() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

>>> kwd_only_arg(arg=3)
3
```